# Deserialize json (javascript object) to c# object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

i have following javascript object it looks like json but when i parse it as json i am getting errors:

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "Manheim Simulcast ",
    "items": {
      "2": {
        "pos": "52",
        "name": "NY - Manheim Albany",
        "address": "",
        "zip": "12201",
        "coords": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and following classes:

```
public class auction_js_min
{
        public auction_id auction_id { set; get; }
    }

    public class auction_id
    {
        public string name { set; get; }
        public Items items { set; get; }
    }

    public class Items
    {
        public Sub_auction_id sub_auction_id { set; get; }

    }

    public class Sub_auction_id
    {
        public string pos { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string zip { get; set; }
        public string coords { get; set; }
    }
```

when i deserialize it to C# object im getting empty object:

```
auction_js_min obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<auction_js_min>(auction_js);
```

is any idea how to fix it? javascript object is too big 87000 symbol and i want iterate over objects and check values.

Comment: You should post the error you're receiving so we can better assist you

Comment: with the following code i did not receive any error, just empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're running into here is that your objects are numbered and you can't name a class with just number. In this case your model doesn't match your JSON so all you're going to get is null. You need to modify your model to match the JSON you have and then you can map that DTO model to something nicer to use in C#.

Here's an example model that deserializes your JSON:

```
public class auction_id
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public IDictionary<int, Sub_auction_id> items { set; get; }
}

public class Sub_auction_id
{
    public string pos { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public string coords { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize like so:

```
public void Deserialize()
{
    var auction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<int, auction_id>>(json);
}
```

Comment: this deserializes part of the json, i'm getting auction name but items object is null again.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make use of JsonProperty here.
Usually these names are invalid but they could be parsed like this.

```cs
public class auction_js_min
{
        [JsonProperty("1")]
        public auction_id auction_id { set; get; }
    }

    public class auction_id
    {
        public string name { set; get; }
        public Items items { set; get; }
    }

    public class Items
    {
        [JsonProperty("2")]
        public Sub_auction_id sub_auction_id { set; get; }

    }

    public class Sub_auction_id
    {
        public string pos { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string zip { get; set; }
        public string coords { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: there is different numbers in the whole string.  it is working for this peace of json.

Answer (score -1):

Thats because of single quotes. Both of the following will work:

- If you know your object is correct, skip the string quotation and directly eval it:

  ```
  eval({'1': {'name': 'Manheim Simulcast','items':{'2':{'pos': '52','name': 'NY - Manheim Albany','address': '','zip': '12201','coords': ''}}}})
  ```
- Or use double quotes inside JSON and single quotes to make it a string likr this:

  ```
  JSON.parse('{"1": {"name": "Manheim Simulcast","items":{"2":{"pos": "52","name": "NY - Manheim Albany","address": "","zip": "12201","coords": ""}}}}')
  ```

As far as parsing them to a C# object. It can be multiple things, need more details.

Comment: The OP is asking how to deserialize the JSON to a C# object, this does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Read the question correctly, the first part talks about JSON parsing: "i have following javascript object it looks like json but when i parse it as json i am getting errors:"

Comment: fair enough but you need to edit your answer for me to remove the downvote